# Laravel Cache testing issue

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mockery

I'm trying to the the following piece of code:

```
public function remember(string $key, \Closure $callback, int $ttl = null): mixed
{
   return \Cache::remember($key, $ttl, $callback);
}
```

with:

```
public function testRememberWhenTimeoutIsSet(): void
{
    \Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
        ->once()
        ->with(\Mockery::on(function ($key, $ttl, $callback) {
            return $key === 'key' && $ttl === 123 && is_callable($callback);
        }))
        ->andReturn('any-thing');

    $this->assertEquals(
        'any-thing',
        $this->service->remember('key', function () {}, 123)
    );
}
```

But it keeps giving me the following error:

> Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException : No matching handler
> found for Mockery_2_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::remember('key',
> 123, object(Closure)). Either the method was unexpected or its
> arguments matched no expected argument list for this method
>
> Objects: ( array (   'Closure' =>    array (
> 'class' => 'Closure',
> 'identity' => '#3e713b47f2e6096de32a4437ee0381ff',
> 'properties' =>
> array (
> ),   ), ))

The error goes away if to completely remove `with` block. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the code below to work well:

```
Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
    ->once()
    ->with('key', 123, \Closure::class)
    ->andReturn('any-thing')
;
```

`with` method in your case doesn't need a `CLOSURE matcher` but only a list of expected arguments.